# Ref C# - new assignment in foo, propagates to other functions using same reference?

Tags: c#

My basic question is asking if I change the reference of a ref in one method is it reflected in the other method (like double pointers in C++)?

```
method()
{
  referenceTypeInt t = new t(1);
  asyncCall foo(ref t);
  bar(ref t);
}

foo(ref a)
{
  a = new t(3);
}
bar (ref a)
{
  wait for 10 seconds/until foo finishes;
  Console.print ("t is" t.ToString())
}
```

The above is rough Pseudoish code, but would t be 3 above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the point of ref. It indicates that the parameter should be treated as an alias to the variable, so assigning to it will alter the the variable itself. Since you ref again in bar, you have another alias, so the change reflected in the output.

Answer (score 1):

That's how `ref` works, in general.

However, there *may* be one point here that's bad.  I'm not sure if this:

```
asyncCall foo(ref t);
```

Was meant to be pseudo code for the new Async CTP (in which case, it should be `await foo(ref t);`).  If that was meant to be an async method call using the new async/await syntax, this won't work.  `ref` and `out` parameters are not supported in `async` methods (similar to how they are not supported in iterators).